# SMS_RECEIVED BroadcastReceiver does not fire when App process is inactive

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have registered a Broadcast receiver to listen to incoming SMS messages. I have observed that the Broadcast receiver does not fire, if my App process is not active.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".SmsBroadcastReceiver"
                  android:enabled="true"
                  android:exported="true"
                  android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
            <intent-filter android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

SmsBroadcastReceiver.java

```
public class SmsBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = SmsBroadcastReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.e(TAG, "New SMS-message received");
        }
    } 
}
```

I have put Log messages on App's onCreate callback and I confirmed that App's onCreate is also not being called when SMS'es are received on the device.

Android Version - 6.0.1
Device - OnePlus 2

Comment: check permission for SMS read and receive  in manifest file

Comment: Already checked that. Confirmed that permissions are present.